# Convert map to 2d array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I am trying to convert a simple map with key-value pairs into a 2d array for example:

```
let myMap = { "key1" => 1, "key2" => 2, "key3" => 3 };
```

to something like this:

```
let myArray = [ ["key1", 1], ["key2", 2], ["key3", 3] ];
```

Comment: it doesnt seem to be a valid object format

Comment: Spread the map inside an array: `[...myMap]`.  It will create an array of entries

Answer (score -2):

Try this function

```js
const myMap = new Map()
myMap.set("key1", 1)
myMap.set("key2", 2)
myMap.set("key3", 3)
myMap.set("key4", 4)


const map2arr = (myMap) => {
  let arr = []
  myMap.forEach((value, key) => arr.push([key, value]))
  return arr
}

console.log(map2arr(myMap))
```